# how to style image button at navigation bar like when hover, link, the image will change the pattern

Tags: html, css, button

I want to made like when hover, active and visited, the image will change to another image, any method?

Now i put the image under background, cause when i put the image, the word will come down, i want to made the word overlap the image, but can't...

if can please explain why need to style like this... i just learn to use html so i want to understand more about it, thanks

```
<div class="navBar" style="margin-left:80px;padding-top:40px;"><!--navBar-->
  <div id="navbar" >
    <div id="navhome" style="width:100px;height:60px; padding-top:30px; padding-left:10px"> <a href="index.html">HOME</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="navhistory" style="width:130px;height:60px; padding-top:30px; padding-left:10px;"> <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="navevent" style="width:130px;height:60px; padding-top:30px; padding-left:10px"> <a href="event_1.html">EVENT</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="navcontact" style="width:130px;height:60px; padding-top:30px;"> <a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--navBar-->
```

**css:**

```
 .navBar {
    font-family: KaiTi;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #6c2e13;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

#navbar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#navhistory {
    background-image: url(../img/nav2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#navevent {
    background-image: url(../img/nav3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#navcontact {
    background-image: url(../img/nav4.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#navhome {
    background-image: url(../img/nav1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Don't style the elements directly in the `html` when you are using external `css` file anyway - which is good. + There shouldn't be more elements with same `id` since is = identifier - it should be unique.

Comment: If you want to have more elements with same style use `class` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing if you want to apply active, visited styles then you need to apply the background images to the anchor tag. So that you can easily update the background image using CSS. At present you are applying background for the div. It means you want to modify the parent element when hover, active or visited actions happened. Using CSS, from child element you can't modify the parent element.

So check my fiddle I have modified your code and applied the same when hover, visited and active actions happened.

Some Sample code:

```
 #navhistory a{
background-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/linear3.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0px 50px;
display:inline-block;
height:60px;
line-height:60px;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#navevent a{
background-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/radial1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0px 50px;
display:inline-block;
height:60px;
line-height:60px;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#navcontact a{
background-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/linear1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0px 50px;
display:inline-block;
height:60px;
line-height:60px;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#navhome a{
background-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/radial3.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0px 50px;
display:inline-block;
height:60px;
line-height:60px;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f56Nr/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want hover effect, than use `:hover` psaudo-class on that element and just change background image. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcLfV/)

```
.button {
   background: url(../img/nav1.png) no-repeat;
}

.button:hover{
   background: url(../img/nav1_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

NOTICE: don't style elements directly (directly writing to `style` attribute. Since you have repeating elements, use `class='someClass subclass sub-subclass'` and than just apply style in `.css` file to all elements with that class:

```
.someClass {
     width: 10px;
     height: 20.5%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: .5em;
}

.someClass.even {
     color: red;
}

.someClass.odd {
     color: green;
}
```